# The third functions while loop isnt working

Tags: python, function, while-loop

basically its while loop problem in the third fucntion.

i will give the code. Then ill show u what happens when i run it and what i want

heres the code

```
def who_do_you_want_to_be(x):
    print("you will be "+x)
    print("Great choice!")
    
def who_do_you_want_to_face(a, x):
    print(a + " will face "+x + "\n" )
    
def Where_do_u_want_to_fight(a):
    
    while True:

        place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
        
        if a=="pokemon stadium":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you pokemon stadium music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        elif a=="planet namek":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you planet namek music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        elif a=="the leaf village":
            print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
            print("Well also give you the leaf village music too but im in a rush")
            break
            
        else:
            print("Spell it correctly!\n")
            

    
    
character=input("write what pokemon you want to be (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower() 
who_do_you_want_to_be(character)

choice=input("\nwrite what pokemon you want to face (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :").lower()    
who_do_you_want_to_face(character, choice)

place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
Where_do_u_want_to_fight(place)
```

now that i showed the code. the third function gives this when i run it

```
write what pokemon you want to be (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :charzard
you will be charzard
Great choice!

write what pokemon you want to face (charzard, pikachu, or Gyarados) :pikachu
charzard will face pikachu
```

//heres where the problem is//

```
choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village):  
pokemon stadium
choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village):  
pokemon stadium
Not today but maybe tomorrow
Well also give you pokemon stadium music too but im in a rush
```

//it asks to choose to fight question twice for no reason. I have the input in the while loop and outside it too but i dont know how to make it function other wise (when i cut it i face other problems)

//and my last issue is//

```
choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village):  
s
Spell it correctly!


choose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village):  
the leaf village
Spell it correctly!
```

//when they choose the fight spot wrong (spelled incorrectly) it run the else statement (spell it correctly) then it loops back up and say choose again. Then when you actually do spell it right it just goes back to the else statement. I dont know what to do?

Comment: Its a typo. You have two `input()`s, but you only actually want one.

Comment: Alternatively, like in my comment to your previous question, you could move the `input()` within the function to be the last line and make it like: `a=input("choose ...`

Answer (score 0):

The `Where_do_u_want_to_fight` function takes an argument, which is the place where you want to fight, and then *also* asks the user where they want to fight (but it ignores the result):

```
def Where_do_u_want_to_fight(a):
    
    while True:

        place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
        
        if a=="pokemon stadium":
```

Note that `a` is the argument you initially called the function with, and `place` is what you just asked the user.  You're never using `place`, so no matter how many times you loop and get a new `place`, you're always checking the original `a`.

To fix this, remove the argument.  Since you already are asking for input inside the function, it's redundant:

```
def Where_do_u_want_to_fight():  # no argument
    
    while True:

        place=input("\nchoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()
        
        if place == "pokemon stadium":  # check 'place', not 'a'
```

When you call it, call it with no argument:

```
Where_do_u_want_to_fight()  # no 'place' argument needed here
```

Comment: But, if you do that, it makes that function unlike the other functions written.

Comment: Yes; OP would do well IMO to understand that difference since it will probably lead them to some insights about scoping  :)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're encountering a couple of issues in your `Where_do_u_want_to_fight` function. Let's address them step by step.

1. **Repeating Input Issue:**
   The reason the "choose to fight" question is asked twice is because you have the input prompt both inside the `while` loop and outside of it. To resolve this, you should only have the input prompt inside the loop.

   Here's the corrected part of your code for the input prompt:

   ```py
   def Where_do_u_want_to_fight(a):
       while True:
           place = input("\nChoose to fight in either (pokemon stadium, planet namek, or the leaf village): ").lower()

           if place == "pokemon stadium":
               print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
               print("We'll also give you pokemon stadium music too but I'm in a rush")
               break
           elif place == "planet namek":
               print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
               print("We'll also give you planet namek music too but I'm in a rush")
               break
           elif place == "the leaf village":
               print("Not today but maybe tomorrow")
               print("We'll also give you the leaf village music too but I'm in a rush")
               break
           else:
               print("Choose a valid location!")
   ```
2. **Incorrect Spelling Handling:**
   To handle the incorrect spelling issue, you need to change the variable you're checking. You are currently checking if `a` (the character you want to face) is equal to a location (e.g., `"pokemon stadium"`). Instead, you should be checking if `place` (the chosen fight location) is equal to the correct location strings.

   I've corrected this in the updated function code provided above.

With these corrections, your `Where_do_u_want_to_fight` function should work as intended. It will keep asking for a valid fight location until the user enters a correct choice, and then it will break out of the loop and proceed accordingly.